# How to block access to a folder except from internal pages

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, http

I have a very simple page on which users can log in and download a pdf.  The path to the pdf is pulled directly from the database and echo'd into a link. Everything about my script works great except I need to block just anyone from being able to access the folder of pdfs.  I have tried adding an htaccess file to the pdf directory with the following:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from localhost
```

As well as several other variations of that,  each time it just breaks the link to the pdf.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'll probably have to make a php script to actually get the pdf and trigger a download. Echoing the link is not enough, as the user is not localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echoing a link to get directly the PDF is not enough. `Allow from localhost` means the server can access it, but not the user. So you will have to make a kind of "proxy" php script to make the server trigger the download :

```
<?php
$pathToThePdf = $_GET['pdf_path'];

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="mydownload.pdf"');

readfile($pathToThePdf);
```

And then in your initial php script, you echo a link to that proxy :

```
echo '<a href="/path/to/proxy.php?pdf_path='.$thePdfPath.'">download</a>';
```

Obviously, you will want to add some security to this proxy by checking if the user is logged.

Answer (score 0):

If you change `localhost` to the IP address or the server IP, it will work.

If you're specifically going to `http://localhost` you need to use `::1`, otherwise use the IP address of the server.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from ::1
```